# Cycle through placeholder text in form with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm fairly new to JQuery, so I wasn't sure where to start on this problem.

I have a form on a website that I want to show various placeholders temporarily and cycle through them (to imitate a number of options the user could input there; like Alice, Bob, Charles, etc. for a NAME form input) before the user clicks to input their own text.

I found this example – http://jsfiddle.net/eFjnU/ (code below) – that cycles through text, but how could I apply that to the temporary placeholders in a form input area?

HTML

```
<div id="content-1">Sample text 1</div>
<div id="content-2">Sample text 2</div>
<div id="content-3">Sample text 3</div>
<div id="content-4">Sample text 4</div>
<div id="content-5">Sample text 5</div>
<div id="content-6">Sample text 6</div>
<div id="content-7">Sample text 7</div>
```

JQuery

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(400)
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(400, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

You can change the above from div to input, but that will cycle the entire input box in and out, and I want only the placeholder text to fade in/out.

**EDIT 1:**

For example:

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" type="text" placeholder="Alice">
<input type="text" name="whatever" type="text" placeholder="Bob">
<input type="text" name="whatever" type="text" placeholder="Charles">
```

Comment: It's not really clear what's you're trying to do

Comment: And you want them all on the same input?

Comment: you can't animate placeholder text, at the most you can have it appear/disappear, like this http://jsfiddle.net/UrLnJ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't animate placeholder text but you can create a function that changes the attribute periodically:

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrLnJ/1/)**

```
var placeholders = ['Alice','Bob','Charles'];

(function cycle() { 
    var placeholder = placeholders.shift();
    $('input').attr('placeholder',placeholder);
    placeholders.push(placeholder);
    setTimeout(cycle,1000);
})();
```

That's basically what you want minus the fadeIn/fadeOut

Comment: @FaceOfJock `delay()` only works with the animation queue by default, also if you're going to use delay you have to call it on an element, it's not a global function

Comment: i tried to use setTimeout also , but it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/kADwN/
Any suggestion ?

Comment: @FaceOfJock you need to wrap the timeout code inside an anonymous function and if your going to go for a loop, you need to increment the timeout delay with each iteration http://jsfiddle.net/kADwN/1/

Answer (score 0):

The place holder text needs a container. This could be anything. As simple as a span or label tag above or below the input fields.

Comment: Not sure if that will work; see new edit. I'm looking to cycle through the input tag's placeholder text.